# Core Data EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: swift, core-data

Here is the code that I have used throughout my project without any issues:

```
var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!
```

Yet it's crashing! Any ideas why??
More code:

```
//now get old current and revoke that

            var context:NSManagedObjectContext = self.appDel.managedObjectContext!



            var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DownloadedCharacters")

            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isCurrent = %@", true)



            var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!



            //error check

            if results.count == 1 {

                //good

                let object:NSManagedObject = results[0] as NSManagedObject

                object.setValue(false, forKey: "isCurrent")

                println("Revoked old current Object, 1")

                //update currents

                //find the new object in storage based off saved name

                let lookupName = cell.cellData?.valueForKey("saveName") as String

                var request2 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DownloadedCharacters")

                request2.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

                request2.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "saveName = %@", lookupName)

                var results2:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request2, error: &self.error)!

                if results2.count == 1 {

                    let object = results2.firstObject as NSManagedObject

                    object.setValue(true, forKey: "isCurrent")

                    println("Updated new current")     

                } else {

                    println("Fatal error in retreving object for Core Data. Count = \(results.count).")

                }

                //now update the section of the table

                tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)


            }
```

Very frustrating. Also, AFTER the problematic line, println("Revoked old current Object, 1") IS being called and IS printing to console.......... any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the error message that you get when running your code?

Comment: It refuses to spit out one! I keep hitting continue, disabling all breakpoints, everything, and insists on staying crashed on that line!

Comment: Is there no error code to go along with the EXC_BREAKPOINT message? That's quite strange...

Comment: code = 1 that shows alongside the problematic line… but nothing in spit out in console

Comment: Have you looked at the call stack? Here's a good tutorial that may help - http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1